# Validate all possibilities of two outcomes

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

So I'm  getting a callback with two outcomes:

```
positive: url.com?scope=read_write&code={AUTHORIZATION_CODE}&state={csrf}

negative: url.com?error=access_denied&error_description=The%20user%20denied%20your%20request
```

I would like to validate all possibilities. My current approach is:

```
$data = request()->validate([
  'scope' => 'required_without:error, error_description',
  'code' => 'required_without:error, error_description',
  'state' => 'required_without:error, error_description',

  'error' => 'required_without:scope,code,state',
  'error_description' => 'required_without:scope,code,state'
]);
```

Actually, it works super fine for every possibility but somehow not for:

```
$this->get(route('connect.index', [
    'error' => $this->error,
    'error_description' => $this->error_description,
]));

dd(session('errors'));
```

The weird part is that I get the error:

```
  #messages: array:3 [
        "scope" => array:1 [
          0 => "The scope field is required when error / error description is not present."
        ]
        "code" => array:1 [
          0 => "The code field is required when error / error description is not present."
        ]
        "state" => array:1 [
          0 => "The state field is required when error / error description is not present."
        ]
      ]
```

But that is not true since I see that the values error, error_description are present!

```
array(2) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(2) "ok"
  ["error_description"]=>
  string(5) "state"
}
```

---

***Update***

@DigitalDrifter helped me, but now, I have got two new test-cases that fail!

```
$this->get(route('connect.index', [
    'scope' => $this->scope,
    'code' => $this->code,
    'error' => $this->error,
    'error_description' => $this->error_description,
]))
    ->assertStatus(302);

$this->get(route('connect.index', [
    'scope' => $this->scope,
    'code' => $this->code,
    'state' => $this->error,
    'error_description' => $this->error_description,
]))
    ->assertStatus(302);
```

As you might see I'm expecting to get a Response of 302 but I get 200. It should not be the case. I'm using @DigitalDrifter answer:

```
$data = request()->validate([
        'scope' => 'bail|sometimes|required_without:error,error_description',
        'code' => 'bail|sometimes|required_without:error,error_description',
        'state' => 'bail|sometimes|required_without:error,error_description',

        'error' => 'bail|required_without:scope,code,state',
        'error_description' => 'bail|required_without:scope,code,state',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Might have luck with [sometimes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#conditionally-adding-rules):

> **Validating When Present**
>   In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list:

```
$data = request()->validate([
  'scope'             => 'bail|sometimes|required_without:error,error_description',
  'code'              => 'bail|sometimes|required_without:error,error_description',
  'state'             => 'bail|sometimes|required_without:error,error_description',
  'error'             => 'bail|required_without:scope,code,state',
  'error_description' => 'bail|required_without:scope,code,state'
]);
```

Comment: Not bad! It helped me, but now I have got two new cases that are false. I edited in my post above. Perhaps you have an idea. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Does the [required_without_all](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-without-all) rule work for error and error_description?

Comment: No :( I'm not sure, do you mean 'error' => 'bail|required_without_all' etc or in scope, code, state? Nonetheless, I tried it both ways. In error/error description I get even a assertStatus of 500 without Exception Handling I get the error: ErrorException: Undefined index: error_description. Why is that so hard with validation? :D